# JQuery ui tabs by class not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Since the jquery-ui tab works with ids instead of class tags, I created a function to generate ids for all my classes. Now I want to add new content and apply the same to that new content, but after adding new content all other tabs stop working!

This is the html content:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Product x</h3>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General product info</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            general info for product x.
        </div>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            end user info product x.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Product y</h3>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General info</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            general info for product y.
        </div>
        <div class="tabpanel">
            end user info product y.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I'm trying to do with it:

```
function fixtabs(){
    $(".tabpanellink").each(
        function(uniqueindex){
            $(this).attr('href', '#tab-' + uniqueindex);
        }
    );
    $(".tabpanel").each(
        function(uniqueindex){
            $(this).attr('id', 'tab-' + uniqueindex);
        }
    );

    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
}
function updateDocument(){
    fixtabs();
    $(".tabs").tabs();
}

function addProduct(){
    //Add another product(this is a server response in a real case scenario):
    var newProduct = '';
    newProduct += '<div class="accordion">';
    newProduct +=   '<h3>Product z</h3>';
    newProduct +=   '<div class="tabs">';
    newProduct +=       '<ul>';
    newProduct +=           '<li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General product info</a></li>';
    newProduct +=           '<li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>';
    newProduct +=       '</ul>';
    newProduct +=       '<div class="tabpanel">';
    newProduct +=           'general info for new product.';
    newProduct +=       '</div>';
    newProduct +=       '<div class="tabpanel">';
    newProduct +=           'end user info product x.';
    newProduct +=       '</div>';
    newProduct +=   '</div>';
    newProduct += '</div>';
    $(".accordion").first().before(newProduct);
    updateDocument();
}
updateDocument();
addProduct();
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as766/).

How to apply the tab effect on the new content without corrupting the existing tabs?

**Update in response to answers:** I can't remove `updateProduct();`! I have to call updateDocument first so everything is initialized! addProduct is only called afterwards (i.e. when user clicks add product!)

Comment: You are using `uniqueindex` as a parameter name in the `each` calls. This will not increment the `uniqueindex` variable ourside the each you were expecting, but will only increment the parameter only! Just drop the parameter and move `uniqueindex` to above the first call to each.

Comment: why you are adding content dynamically ??

Comment: Do you mean `newProduct += etc...`? Its to show what content comes from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Now try this its working fine with your add product option**

**

### Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as766/5/)

**

Add another Div as parent Div

```
<div id="accor">    

<div class="accordion">
        <h3>Product x</h3>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <!-- .tabs-0 & .tabs-1 don't work, since they are not a valid url -->
                <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General product info</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tabpanel">
                general info for product x.
            </div>
            <div class="tabpanel">
                end user info product x.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>Product y</h3>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <!-- .tabs-0 & .tabs-1 don't work, since they are not a valid url -->
                <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General info</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tabpanel">
                general info for product y.
            </div>
            <div class="tabpanel">
                end user info product y.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="AddProduct"> add product</button >
```

And at your Jquery code will be like this -

```
function fixtabs(){
    $(".tabpanellink").each(
        function(uniqueindex){
            $(this).attr('href', '#tab-' + uniqueindex);
            uniqueindex++;
        }
    );
    uniqueindex = 0;
    $(".tabpanel").each(
        function(uniqueindex){
            $(this).attr('id', 'tab-' + uniqueindex);
            uniqueindex++;
        }
    );

    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
}
function updateDocument(){
    fixtabs();
    $(".tabs").tabs();
}

function addProduct(){
    //Add another product:
    var newProduct = '';
    newProduct += '<div class="accordion">';
    newProduct +=   '<h3>Product z</h3>';
    newProduct +=   '<div class="tabs">';
    newProduct +=       '<ul>';
    newProduct +=           '<li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General product info</a></li>';
    newProduct +=           '<li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>';
    newProduct +=       '</ul>';
    newProduct +=       '<div class="tabpanel">';
    newProduct +=           'general info for new product.';
    newProduct +=       '</div>';
    newProduct +=       '<div class="tabpanel">';
    newProduct +=           'end user info product x.';
    newProduct +=       '</div>';
    newProduct +=   '</div>';
    newProduct += '</div>';
    $("#accor").first().append(newProduct);
    updateDocument();
   //$(".tabs").tabs();
    //fixtabs();
}
//addProduct();
updateDocument();

$('#AddProduct').click(function(){
addProduct();
//$(".tabs").tabs();
//updateDocument();
});
```

Comment: By the way incrementing uniqueindex is not necessary! Just adding a new div did the trick! See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EgXa9/)

Comment: yeah i did not increment the uniqueindex i just followed your question :P

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine now -

Just call your `addProduct();` function before `updateDocument();`

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/as766/4/)

```
function fixtabs(){
$(".tabpanellink").each(
    function(uniqueindex){
        $(this).attr('href', '#tab-' + uniqueindex);
        uniqueindex++;
    }
);
uniqueindex = 0;
$(".tabpanel").each(
    function(uniqueindex){
        $(this).attr('id', 'tab-' + uniqueindex);
        uniqueindex++;
    }
);

$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
}

function updateDocument(){
    fixtabs();
    $(".tabs").tabs();
}

function addProduct(){
    //Add another product:
    var newProduct = '';
    newProduct += '<div class="accordion">';
    newProduct +=   '<h3>Product z</h3>';
    newProduct +=   '<div class="tabs">';
    newProduct +=       '<ul>';
    newProduct +=           '<li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">General product info</a></li>';
    newProduct +=           '<li><a href="" class="tabpanellink">End user info</a></li>';
    newProduct +=       '</ul>';
    newProduct +=       '<div class="tabpanel">';
    newProduct +=           'general info for new product.';
    newProduct +=       '</div>';
    newProduct +=       '<div class="tabpanel">';
    newProduct +=           'end user info product x.';
    newProduct +=       '</div>';
    newProduct +=   '</div>';
    newProduct += '</div>';
    $(".accordion").first().before(newProduct);
    updateDocument();
}
addProduct();
updateDocument();
```

Comment: I can't do that! I have to call updateDocument first so everything is initialized! addProduct is only called afterwards (i.e.) when user clicks add product!